# Private virtual function of base is hidden by private virtual function of derived

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution

The following code

```
class A
{
public:
    void g(int x)
    {
        f(x);
    }

protected:
    virtual void f(int) = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
protected:
    virtual void f(float) = 0;

private:
    void f(int x) override final
    {
        f(float(x));
    }
};

class C: public B
{
private:
    void f(float) override final {}
};

int
main()
{
    C c;
    c.g(1);

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `g++ -Woverloaded-virtual` produces said warning:

```
x.cc:19:7: warning: ‘virtual void B::f(int)’ was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  void f(int x) override final
       ^
x.cc:28:7: warning:   by ‘virtual void C::f(float)’ [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  void f(float) override final {}
       ^
```

I do not understand what is being hidden here. From the scope of `C` there is only one possible overload to `f` as `B::f(int)` is private within `C`.

From the scope of `B` there are two, but both are explicitly named inside `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is telling you that the function `C::f(float)` hides `B::f(int)`, and that's because [it does](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#2). Access specifiers don't affect overloading, so the fact that `B::f(int)` is private doesn't matter. Even if `B::f(int)` was public, it wouldn't be considered for overload resolution, and that's what "hiding" refers to.

Comment: But what is the point of this warning then? It warns me about something that in fact does not apply to my situation. How can I get rid of it (other then `#pragma diagnostics` switch)?

Comment: @TFM, `C*c=new C; c->f(int{});` here f(float) will be chosen for dispatching. but here `B * b = c ; b -> f( int{} )` f means f(int). for example, if you have following hierarchy `struct A{ virtual void f(int),f(float); }; struct B:A{void f(float);}; struct C:B{void f(int),f(float);};` then via B's iface you can dispatch only f(float), unless you explicitly qualify f's name with A's (b_iface->A::f(int{})).

Comment: @GreenTree I understand what this warning means in a situation in which it actually makes sense. I'm trying to understand its implications in my situation.

Comment: @TFM, it makes sense from point of language. "From the scope of C there is only one possible overload to f as B::f(int) is private within C". this wording is not right. it will be found if C will be defined as struct C : B { } obj ; obj.f( int{} ) ;.this code should not compile because B::f( int ) is private, but not because it's not visible. privatness of f( int ) doesn't affect overload resolution. that is why struct { void f ( float ) { } private : void f ( int ) { } } obj ; obj.f( int{} ) ; should not compile - f founded, but it's private.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html):

> `-Woverloaded-virtual` (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
>       Warn when a function declaration hides virtual functions from a base class. For example, in:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>     virtual void f();
> };
>
> struct B: public A {
>     void f(int);
> };
> ```
>
> the `A` class version of `f` is hidden in `B`, and code like:
>
> ```
> B* b;
> b->f();
> ```
>
> fails to compile.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand what is being hidden here. From the scope of `C` there is only one possible overload to `f` as `B::f(int)` is `private` within `C`.

Name lookup and resolution happens before access rules are applied.

`B::f(int)` is hidden by `C::f(float)` when the name `f` is looked up from a `C` object. That's what the compiler is warning you about.